# Pass an object id to rails mailer view when object is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to send email notifications to followers of a business when the business updates a post. This is the setup I have:

```
def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_index_path, notice: "Updated post"
    format.json { render :'shows/show', status: :ok, location: @post }
    update_page_email_followers 
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update_page_email_followers
  @followers = Follow.where(business_id: current_business.id)
  @followers.each do |follower|
    ModelMailer.delay.update_post(@user, follower, @post)
  end
end
```

This is the mailer method:

```
def update_post(post follower, business_id)
  @business = Business.find(follower.business_id)
  @post = post
  @user = User.find(follower.user_id)
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "#{@business.account.business_name} updated a post")
end
```

And this is what I have inside the mail view template `update_post.html.erb`:

```
<%= @business.account.business_name %> has just updated a post! Please click on <%= link_to "Updated post", "https://www.example.com/sample-#{@post.id}" %>
```

The mail notification is being sent correctly to all the followers I just cant get the id of the post on the email view from this : `<%= link_to "Updated post", "https://www.example.com/sample-#{@post.id}" %>`... it comes out as `nil`.

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: " it comes out as nil" - not surprising. Look at the order in which `update_post` expects things to be passed. And the order in which you actually pass them.

Comment: try to debug in update_post method , what value you get of post in that metho

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sergio Tulentsev... So are you suggesting to change the order according to this: `def update_post(post follower, business_id)`.. because I already did this: `@post = post @user = User.find(follower.user_id) @business = Business.find(follower.business_id)` but I still get `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def update_page_email_followers
  @followers = Follow.where(business_id: current_business.id)
  @followers.each do |follower|
    ModelMailer.delay.update_post(@user, follower, @post)
  end
end
```

update post method

```
def update_post(user, follower, post)
  @business = Business.find(follower.business_id)
  @post = post
  @user = User.find(follower.user_id)
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "#{@business.account.business_name} updated a post")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vishal ... I got it to work! :)))

Comment: glad to know that :)